# Are e-ink displays really that sensitive to humidity?

Tags: e-ink

I'm looking into getting a cheap e-ink screen for a project, and when I bring up the datasheet for a candidate, the operating humidity range is always somewhere between "narrow" and "absurdly narrow".  For example, [this one](https://www.pervasivedisplays.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/1P277-00_01_E2741JS0B2_20210223.pdf) has a range of 40%-70%.  Since I live in a part of the world where the humidity rarely gets up to 40%, that's clearly not workable.

Is this just a result of looking at *cheap* screens, or an inherent limitation of e-ink displays?

Comment: You might want to consider asking the manufacturer. It's unusual to have a strict lower limit on humidity. Maybe it's an ESD handling thing. Low humidity will affect the dimensions of polyamide parts though.